# How to expand all search results in QTCreator 2.7

Tags: qt-creator

When I do text search the results display in Search Results frame.
Initially this is a list of file which can be expanded (each file separately).

Is there and option to Expand all at once?
Or maybe there is a different view of search results (like tabular) ?

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no option to automatically expand all files displayed in **Search Results**. But you can configure a keyboard shortcut to the **ExpandAll** command:

1. Select **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Keyboard**.
2. Select **Find** / **ExpandAll** command from the list.
3. In **Key Sequence** enter the shortcut key you want to associate with the selected command. For example Ctrl+Shift+E.

[image: Screenshot of Options window]

When the search results are displayed just press the keyboard shortcut to expand all files.